# Handle login success in adal angular 4

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, angular2-services, adal

I am using [adal-angular4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular4) for AD authentication in angular 4 application. The login works, but I don't see an option to subscribe to a *login success event* or *login response*.

```
import { Adal4Service } from 'adal-angular4';

export class AppComponent { 
  ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();       
    }

  constructor(private adalService: Adal4Service) {      
    this.adalService.init(config);                      
    } 

    login = function () {
      if (!this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
          this.adalService.login().subscribe(res => {
              console.log(res); //This is not executed after redirecting to the app from AD authentication page.
          });
        }
    }
}
```

The below code is seen in AngularJs applications. But not sure how to use in angular 4.

```
$scope.$on("adal:loginSuccess", function () {
        console.log("login success");
    });
```

Comment: No callback property in `Adal4Service`

Comment: @jitender that post is for ADAL.js (Microsoft's official library), this is a different library (not made by Microsoft).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps -

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    this.adalService.getUser(); 

    if (!this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
       this.adalService.login(); //redirects to company AD url
    } else if (this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
       //login success
    } 
 }
```

Comment: may I know what's the use of this.adalService.handleWindowCallback() and this.adalService.getUser()? I couldn't find any explanation regarding the ADAL methods in adal-angular4's documentation. it just has only the instruction of implementation but no explanation of what's it used for...